# Different ajax search on multiple pages - Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i need to perform 2 different searches for 2 different pages
This is first one, and second one would be 10 posts per page and different post type, i've tried using is_page() but it doesn't work since it trows 0 results and i've checked if there are any

```
    function ja_ajax_search() {
        $results = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'      => array( 'post', 'page' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            's'              => stripslashes( $_POST['search'] ),
        ) );


        $items = array();

        if ( ! empty( $results->posts ) ) {
            foreach ( $results->posts as $result ) {
                $items[] = $result->post_title;
            }
        }

        wp_send_json_success( $items );
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' );

/*eslint-disable */

jQuery(function ($) {
  var searchRequest;
  $('#ses').autoComplete({
    minChars: 3,
    source: function (term, suggest) {
      searchRequest = $.post(global.ajax, {search: term, action: 'search_site',tip_pretrage: 'cards'}, function (res) {
        suggest(res.data);
      });
    },
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code from where you are calling this search function?

Comment: Posted @zipkundan

Comment: How are you using action "ja_ajax_search"? I can not find any reference to that action in the new code you have posted.

Comment: it's binded to wp's search option via global.ajax

Comment: so you're trying to use the same jquery ajax call and the same php function on both pages?  any particular reason why you're not just using a different ajax call?